# Transfer procedure for non-connecting flights in Ataturk Istanbul (IST)

Tags: tickets, international-travel, airport-transfer, turkish-airlines, isl

I have an international flight to Istanbul Ataturk airport and then another international flight from there. My flights are not connected but both are with Turkish Airlines. I don't know the procedure for this sort of flights. How should I get my boarding pass and what should I do? Also am I considered as a transit/transfer passenger?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: You can check in for your departing flight without clearing immigration; there is at least one transit desk in the "international" zone for this purpose.  However, if you have checked luggage that will be another matter.  You may be able to get the airline to check the bags through, but if you cannot, you'll have to clear immigration to retrieve them.